# "Multiple locks on web thread not allowed" crash as a result of calling present(viewcontroller...)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11, presentviewcontroller

The crash I'm getting is:

> Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...

The crash happens when I instantiate a custom view controller called `setupViewController` and call:

```
present(setupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have debugged the error quite a bit and here's what I know about it:

- It only happens on iOS 11, iOS 10.3.3 is fine
- Nothing inside the `setupViewController` is causing the crash, it is just the presentation of it. If I take all code and all views out of the controller, it still crashes.
  (Also: I'm running an iPhone 6s simulator)

From what I understand, this crash is happening because I tried to update a UI component from a secondary thread. I have tried calling the functions from the main thread like such:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let setupViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuickSetup") as! QuickSetupViewController
    self.present(setupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is obviously not enough for us to reproduce the problem. Can you help us identify [what we have to add to a blank project in order to reproduce your crash](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Rob Theoretically, all you would have to do is create 2 view controllers. Lets call them "main" and "second." Main is the initial view controller. Inside its "viewDidAppear" method, you would put the code that creates and presents the second view. (ie: the code in the question that has let setupViewcontroller = self.storyboard...) That is all that is happening which makes the crash. In my project, the quicksetup can be empty but it still has the same problem.

Comment: That's a good clarification (and you should edit your question to include this `viewDidAppear` stuff, because that's a new piece of information). But still, I created a blank project, put your above code in `viewDidAppear` of initial view controller, and did _not_ get your error on iOS 11 simulator from Xcode 9. The "web thread" in your error message makes me suspect that there's still something else going on. Again, I'd suggest you actually create a blank project and start adding stuff and identify what is necessary to reproduce the problem (not in theory, but in practice).

Comment: As per your description, the problem could be in the following place: The controller who is presenting the QuickSetupViewController has some other code that tries to run something on different queue and causes crash. Try completely comment out the presentation code to make sure where the problem is. It's very hard to say something surely with this minimal info.